# iOS - Xcode stopped displaying iOS version for the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Very confused why my Xcode 6.4 suddenly stopped showing the iOS version for the simulators. Now, it just displays some identifier for each simulator and it is very annoying and hard for me to navigate between simulators.

[image: See here]

I also have the Xcode 7 - Beta 4 installed. But i do not think that is the reason though. Because, earlier i've had Xcode 7 Betas along with Xcode 6.x and it used to work just fine;

Wanted to find out if others have faced the problem and a possible solution.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens to me a lot when I have installed multiple versions or updates of Xcode. Sometimes it helps just to quit Xcode and restart the computer. If that doesn't solve it, I simply open the Devices window (Window > Devices in Xcode) and delete all the simulators. Then I recreate simulators, one by one, that I actually want. This causes Xcode to behave properly again.